# I need an explanation to C# program output

Tags: c#

```cs
using System;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        PrintMethod("Hello World");
    }
    
    static void PrintMethod(object x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("object called");
    }
    
    static void PrintMethod<T>(params T[] x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("params T method called[]");
    }
}
```

Output: `params T method called[]`

Can someone help me with the explanation? I want to know why we are not using first printMethod

Comment: [Overload method resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/language-specification/overload-resolution)

Comment: If we infer `T` to be `string`, the second method is an exact match. Why wouldn't it be chosen?

Comment: `"Hello World"` is a string, not an object, therefore the second method is chosen based on the rules outlined in @Steve's link.

Comment: "Hello World" is a string _and_ an object.

Comment: @DStanley: The first sentence in the link provided above reads: *"In practice, the rules for determining overload resolution are intended to find the overload that is 'closest' to the actual arguments supplied."*

Comment: Thankyou all for clarifying my query

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was just being nitpicky...

Answer (score -1):

Check [here](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Overloading) about function overloading order.

The idea is that `object` is always last in overload order.